# Bootstrap3 burger menu

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

Как сделать в Bootstrap3, чтобы `burger menu` появлялось на разрешении 1130px и ниже?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле на сайте самого бутстрапа есть многочисленные примеры. [Вот](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) один из них. Просто изменяйте размеры окна браузера и вы увидите появление бургер меню

Фактически, вы можете воспользоваться теми классами, которые есть в примере.

Вы так же можете изучить [медиа](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media) [запросы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/), как вам уже посоветовали, и создать подобное поведение самостоятельно.

Вот [тут](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone) можно найти примеры медиа-запросов для эппловских таблеток и телефонов.

Comment: у меня есть шаблон. и мне надо изменить разрешение чтобы бургер меню появлялось на 1130, а не при 767

Comment: @YaroslavPolubedov, покажите ваш шаблон.

Comment: Со всем уже разобрался. Спасибо за помощь )))